# Can we use polar coordinates to evaluate $\int_{x=0}^{1} \int_{y=x}^{1}\left(x^{2}+y^{2}\right) d y d x$

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, polar-coordinates, change-of-variable

I am trying to evaluate $$I=\int_{x=0}^{1} \int_{y=x}^{1}\left(x^{2}+y^{2}\right) d y d x$$ using polar coordinates.

The region of the integration is shown above:
[image]

My try:
We have $x=r\cos(\theta), y=r\sin(\theta)$

Now for the above region $\theta \in (45^{\circ}, 90^{\circ})$ But ia mstuck in finding limits of $r$ and i am sure that $r$ depends on $\theta$.

Comment: $y=r sin (\theta)$ and your top boundary is $y<1$

Comment: There's no reason to use polar coordinates here, as it can be done easily in the current form.

Comment: You are on the right track... now you want change any $y$ and $x$ variables in terms of $\theta$: Like $dy = r*\cos(\theta) d\theta$.

Comment: $r$ ranges from $0$ to $\sqrt 2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. If we measure the angle $\theta $ from the positive $y$ axis, the integral takes the form $$I=\int_{\theta=0}^{\pi/4}\int_{r=0}^{\sec\theta}r^2\cdot r\,\mathrm dr\,\mathrm d\theta.$$
The inner integral is $[r^4/4]_0^{\sec\theta}=\frac14\sec^4\theta,$ and so
$$I=\int_{\theta=0}^{\pi/4}\frac14\sec^4\theta\,\mathrm d\theta.$$
Now the transformation $t:=\tan\theta$, with $\mathrm dt=\sec^2\theta\,\mathrm d\theta$, yields
$$I=\int_{t=0}^1\frac14\sec^2\theta\,\mathrm d t=\int_{t=0}^1\frac14(1+t^2)\,\mathrm d t=\frac14\left[t+\frac{t^3}3\right]_0^1=\frac13.$$

Answer (score 3):

Yeah of course.

$y=1\implies r\sin(\theta)=1$.

So $r=\csc(\theta)$.

So you take the Jacobian and change the limits.

$$\int_{\frac{\pi}{4}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\int_{0}^{\csc(\theta)}r^{2}\cdot r\,dr\,d\theta=\frac{1}{3}$$

Comment: +1 since it answers OP's question. To execute this requires finding $\frac14\int_{\pi/4}^{\pi/2}\csc^4\theta\,d\theta$. This seems more tedious than just using rectangular coordinates on the original integral of a polynomial.

Comment: Yeah. It highly complicates the process. Just integrating the polynomials is much much easier.